# iOS: Home and work locations from user

Tags: swift, core-location

iOS has information such as home and work locations of the user. E.g. in the reminders app:

[image: Screenshot of Reminders App]

Is there any way I can access this information in my app? I looked in the documentation of Core Location but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037711/ios-location-services-visits-and-system-frequent-location) SO question provides more information.

Comment: I think that remains an Apple's privilege on iOS. What you need is to [fetch the "me" card](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontactstore/1402987-unifiedmecontactwithkeys). From there, you can get the home and work addresses. Unfortunately, that function is only available on OS X. I can see the privacy complications if it was available on iOS